# How do you expire an action for all formats in Rails? (expire_action)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Let's say I have a hypothetical controller called `ThingsController` that exposes two actions: index and update which have the following routes:

> GET /things  ThingsController#index
>
> PUT /things/1 ThingsController#update

Both actions respond to a JSON format, so you have `GET /things.json` and `PUT things/1.json`

I am caching the index action and the update action is expiring the index action as follows:

```
expire_action :action => :index
```

However when update occurs it does expire the default format for `/things` but it does not expire `/things.json`.

What do I need to do to make `expire_action` expire all formats? I can't seem to find this anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a better way than to explicitly expire each format unfortunately.

```
expire_action :action => :index
expire_action :action => :index, :format => 'json'
```

Comment: Good enough for now, it would be nice to be able to expire all. I should have just tried to pass in format, thought about it for a second but it wasn't in the API docs.